# How to dispose Image object after each reuse

Tags: c#, object, memory, dispose

I have a function that takes screenshot every few seconds and in order to achieve that I am using Timer object.

But the problem is, the memory occupied by the application is increases with time. So I would like to dispose the object created in that function image after it is saved and reuse again.

Code is below

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
    captureScreen();
}

int tempnum = 0;

void captureScreen()
{
    timer1.Interval = 200; // in miliseconds
    ScreenCapture sc = new ScreenCapture();
    Image img = sc.CaptureScreen();
    pictureBox1.Image = img;
    img.Save("C://my//test"+ tempnum +".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    //  img.Dispose();
    tempnum++;
}
```

Is there anyway I can make this code memory efficient or different approach that might help?

Thanks

Comment: There isn't anything inherently memory intensive in the code you've posted.  I'd recommend that you research whether `ScreenCapture()` or `CaptureScreen()` implement anything that's memory intensive.  You might also want to verify whether any of your calls implement `iDisposable` and should therefore be wrapped in a `using` clause

Comment: Also, you should be able to step through your code and monitor a profiler for memory usage.  What line of code is causing your concern?

Comment: `Image` implements `IDisposable`, so you should wrap that in a `using`

Comment: Do not call Dispose while the PBox still expects a valid image. Instead first set PBox.Image= null and then dispose. If you still want to show it, then reverse the order, ie set null and dispose before setting the new image. It that flickers you can intriduce a dummy image variable`: `if (dummy = pbox.Image != null)  dummy = pbox.Image;  pbox.Image=newImage; if (dummy != null ) dummy.Dispose();`

Comment: I think garbage collection was being carried out after 4GB memory usage. And so on. I added System.GC.Collect(); in code and now it seems its working fine now.